# How to make punch hole in Qt Application

Tags: qt

I need to make a punch hole in Qt application so that I can see the video running behind Qt graphics.
My Qt application is using directfb api underneath.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
KBalar

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a punch hole, do you mean a portion of your application that is transparent?  If so, you can use the [mask property of `QWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setMask) to do so.  You can also look at the [clock example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-shapedclock.html).

Comment: I mean if there are multiple screen one over other I want to make portion of all screen should be transparent not only top screen. I want to make punch hole in entire qt graphics.

Comment: @kbalar, what does "multiple screen one over other" mean?